# how to fix ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info while installing geograpy package

Tags: python-3.x

while installing `geograpy` package getting below error message

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
>   egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

install `newspaper3k` still not resovled.

please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command below to install geograpy for Python3.x :

```
pip3 install geograpy3
```